# URLConnection Androidstudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, url, urlconnection

How can i see if a website is available or not?

For example:
https://google.com = true
https://g00gleee.org = false

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public WebView webView;



Writer writer = new StringWriter();
String upordown = "";

public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
    try{
        URL myUrl = new URL("https://dfgdsfgdsgdfsg.com");
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
        upordown = writer.toString();
        return false;
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbtn);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://google.nl");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isConnectedToServer("https://google.com", 100);
            System.out.println(upordown);
        }
    });

}
```

}

When i use the code up here i will receive:

> I/System.out: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
> at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
> at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
> at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
> at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
> I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
> at com.example.httptest.MainActivity.isConnectedToServer(MainActivity.java:32)
> at com.example.httptest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:59)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
> at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

How can i see now if the website is available or not?

Comment: It will throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException to begin with.

Comment: `Unfortunately the code always returns me FALSE` That is no way to describe what happens. Your code throws an exception. And you catch the exception but then you are not printing the stacktrace or logging e.getMessage() so you dont know what happened

Comment: Under the catch i did try using: System.out.println(e.getMessage()); Unfortunately is always prints NULL. Help me out?

Comment: Also adapt your code here to show us what you did.

Comment: `public boolean isConnectedToServer` You cannot define a function in the onClick() event handler. It will not even compile.. And it is unclear where you really call it.

Comment: I updated the code! Maybe now you can understand my problem?

Comment: Repeat: `It will throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException to begin with`

Comment: You did not show where you called isConnectedToServer().

Comment: I updated the full code i hope you will see my problem now? @blackapps

Comment: I told you the problem already in my first comment. And repeated it later. And you can see it in the first line of your log.

Comment: It needs a Asynctask, the problem i cant figure out how i write the code. Can someone give me an example to learn?

Comment: There are hundreds of examples already on stackoverflow. And as much on the rest of internet.